# Is Inline Block Not Working Because Margins Are Set?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to horizontally align two block elements and "display: inline-block" isn't working. I'm wondering if this is because I have unique margins set for each element. I don't understand CSS from a theoretical level. I will be adding a line to connect them visually once they're on the same horizontal line.

```css
h2 {
  padding: 75px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
}

#cal {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  border: solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 350px;
  margin-right: 250px;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="#about-me">About Me</h2>

<p id="cal">My name is Cal. I'm 28 years old and live in Boston, Massachusetts. I'm from NYC originally. I'm passionate about web design and SEO. I built this site to feature my work.</p>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Without your HTML, we have no idea what you see or are trying to achieve. Please edit your question with the HTML you are working with. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: try this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation